# No permissions for notifications

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

The problem is that when run this extension I get the `SecurityError DOM 18` when trying to make that notification.

So this is how my manifest file looks like:

```
{
 "name": "No",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "version": "1",
 "content_scripts": [
  {
   "js": ["js.js"]
  }
 ], 
 "permissions": [
 "notifications", "tabs"
 ],
 "web_accessible_resources": [
 "48.png"
 ]
}
```

This is the notification:

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
    '/favicon.ico',
    'Item added to cart!',  // notification title
    'Item ............ has been successfully added to the cart.'  //       notification body text
);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to declare `window` or `chrome` before `webkitNotificacions`.

Answer (score 2):

The `notifications` permission does not propagate to the content script.

Add an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html) to your extension, and [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to open the notification from the event page.